# Is there a library or suggested tactic for shift planning with hours and breaks?

Tags: python, pandas, math, optimization

I’m trying to think through a sort of extra credit project- optimizing our schedule.

Givens:

- “demand” numbers that go down to the 1/2 hour. These tell us the ideal number of people we’d have on at any given time;
- 8 hour shift, plus an hour lunch break > 2 hours from the start and end of the shift (9 hours from start to finish);
- Breaks: 2x 30 minute breaks in the middle of the shift;
- For simplicity, can assume an employee would have the same schedule every day.

Desired result:

- Dictionary or data frame with the best-case distribution of start times, breaks, lunches across an input number of employees such that the difference between staffed and demanded labor is minimized.

I have pretty basic python, so my first guess was to just come up with all of the possible shift permutations (points at which one could take breaks or lunches), and then ask python to select x (x=number of employees available) at random a lot of times, and then tell me which one best allocates the labor. That seems a bit cumbersome and silly, but my limitations are such that I can’t see beyond such a solution.

I have tried to look for libraries or tools that help with this, but the question here- how to distribute start times and breaks within a shift- doesn’t seem to be widely discussed. I’m open to hearing that this is several years off for me, but...

Appreciate anyone’s guidance!

Comment: Your on the right path: You're thinking about and documenting requirements; You're thinking about and writing down how to implement different aspects of those requirements. Now you just need to get familiar with a language and pick one of those aspects and write code to implement it, then the next one, .... It never hurts to write stuff down with pencil and paper first. don't loose sight of the *big picture* either, all the little things need to fit together.

Comment: I appreciate that @wwii. I've figured out, thus far, how to get a iterable object of all of the possible permutations that meet my criteria, and fairly efficiently. I'll keep plugging.